# Can't read js file from url in correct encoding

Tags: java, url, utf-8, fileutils

I want to read js file as string from url https://d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-67008-473432.js

I tried several ways (to read from url or to download and then read), but all the time I received unreadable characters, like �(��_�s��d������:`���.����i�.... 
The ways I tried it:
1. dowload file from url:

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(jsUrl, file);
```

2. read from url:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(jsUrl);
        // read text returned by server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

If I download the file manually from the url (page-> save as...) - it could be opened with Notepad++ in normal UTF-8 encoding.
Could anybody help me to handle the weird file?

Comment: you can use JSOUP to parse the document https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url  \n  or you can use OKHTTP to download the file and parse it UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's GZIPped. Use a `GZIPInputStream`.

UPDATE

```
        InputStream stream = url.openStream();
        if ("gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(cnt.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding"))) {
            stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
        }
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
```

UPDATE 2

With URLConnection:

```
        URLConnection cnt = url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = cnt.getInputStream();
        if ("gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(cnt.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding"))) {
            stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
        }
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Need to add to code snippet: `URLConnection cnt = url.openConnection();`

Comment: another link that I can't read https://www.hellobank.fr/rsc/contrib/script/hb2/js/app/pages/video-bienvenue.js